# How do i properly code this java calculator?

Tags: java

I am creating a java calculator, and I am encountering a situation involving my java scanner being unable to accept any more input.
Here is the code im working with:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RealCalc {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner bucky = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner reason = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner finalProduct = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fnum, snum, answer;
        String YesNo;
        String Multiply;
        String Add;
        String Divide;
        String Subtract;
        String operation;

        // Time to declare the string's value
        Multiply = ("Multiply");
        Divide = ("Divide");
        Subtract = ("Subtract");
        Add = ("Add");

        System.out.println("Hello, my name is Cortana,"
                + " would you like to perform operations with me?");

        YesNo = reason.nextLine();
        if (YesNo.equals("Yes")) {
            System.out.println("Good choice!");
            System.out.println(" ");

            System.out.println("Enter your first number");
            fnum = bucky.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter your second number");
            snum = bucky.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("What do you want me to do with these numbers?");
            operation = finalProduct.nextLine();
            if (operation.equals(Multiply)) {

                System.out.println(fnum * snum);

            } else {

                System.out.println("I do not recognize this operation");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So basically the problem is near the end when I am trying to find a way to code a thing where it asks you to type an operation you want to perform.
If you say Multiply, Divide, Add, or Subtract, it will do that respected operation with firstNum and secondNum (fnum, snum), but if it is neither of those 4 operations, it will say "I do not recognize this operation.
Now this isn't difficult. The problem is getting to retry typing in an operation.
When it says "I do not recognize" the program im using (eclipse) does not allow me to input any more data.
Please help.

Comment: Don't use multiple scanners on the same input file.

Comment: To define a name for a constant value, use e.g. `private static final String MUTIPLY = "Multiply";`, to be written at class level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another simple way to do it: wrapp the code area with the issue in a `while(true)`and use a `break` to finish when it has been answered

```
 while (true) {
     System.out.println("What do you want me to do with these numbers?");
        operation = finalProduct.nextLine();

        if (operation.equals(Multiply)){

            System.out.println(fnum * snum);
            break;

        }else{

            System.out.println("I do not recognize this operation");

        }
     }
```

This way your application will keep looping every time the user inputs an incorrect operation and will finish only when he inputs `Multiply`

The construct like `while(true)` is used to create an infinite loop, so all the code inside the while block will keep running unless it encounters a break, which will happen only when he inputs the right operator and after the program outputs the answers. Otherwise if he inputs something incorrect the program will answer `I do not recognize this operation`and will start over again by asking him again to input the operator

Comment: I'm sorry for being a bother, but I don't get what the while (true) is specifying needs to be true? What needs to be true in order for it to be octet? Also, What does the break command do?

Comment: So how would I implement this idea with multiple possible correct answers? I.E: Multiply, Divide, Add, Subtract? Would I just create more of the if statements before the first break, or create more breaks?

Comment: This is what I have come up with:

      `System.out.println("What do you want me to do with these numbers?");
      while (true) {
         operation = finalProduct.nextLine();
         if (operation.equals(Multiply)){

             System.out.println(fnum * snum);
             break;
            operation = finalProduct.nextLine();
          
          if (operation.equals(Divide)){

              System.out.println(fnum / snum);
              break;

         }else{
         }
             System.out.println("I do not recognize this operation");`
I am getting a "Unreachable Code" error :/

Comment: @Peter_Browning you have small errors: use  `while (true) {
        System.out.println("What do you want me to do with these numbers?");
           operation = finalProduct.nextLine();
           
           if (operation.equals(Multiply)){
   
               System.out.println(fnum * snum);
               break;
   
           } else if (operation.equals(Divide)) {
            
            System.out.println(fnum/snum);
            break;
            
           } else{
   
               System.out.println("I do not recognize this operation");
   
           }
          }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String answer="";
String option="";

boolean status=true;
while(status){
Scanner num=new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner lin=new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner opt=new Scanner(System.in);


double numA,numB,result=0;

System.out.println("\"WELCOME TO JAVA CALCULATOR\"");
System.out.println("Enter The First Number");
numA=num.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter The Second Number");
numB=num.nextDouble();
System.out.println("What You Want To Calculate?");
answer=lin.nextLine();

if(answer.equals("+")){
    result=numA+numB;}
if(answer.equals("-")){
    result=numA-numB;}
if(answer.equals("*")){
    result=numA*numB;}
if(answer.equals("/")){
    result=numA/numB;}
System.out.println("The Result Is:"+result);
System.out.println("Do You Want To Contenue?");
option=opt.nextLine();

if(option.equals("y")){
    status=true;}
if(option.equals("n")){
    System.exit(0);
```

Comment: look you have to understand the codes in my post it's very simple to understand. read 3-4 times you can do that.....:)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use `while(continue == 'Y')` loop with statement at the end of it like "press Y if you want to continue or any key to terminate".

Where and what to put in `while` depends what you want to achieve. If you want to receive all data new (`fnum, snum, operation`), then while loop must start before line

```
System.out.println("Enter your first number");
```

if you want only operation to be re-entered by user then use while loop

```
System.out.println("Enter your first number");
```

This is the basic version. You can of course enchant it more.

Comment: I should have stated that im very inexperienced at java and I'm not sure how to properly implement a loop program, or even while commands. Anther thing: If continue would be a string variable, wouldn't it be while(continue.equals("Y")){

Comment: @Peter_Browning At least you know how to compare strings. That's a good start :). Loops is a basic and fundamental concept which you have to learn and understand to even start your programming journey and there is plenty of materials how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

**A working calculator (that re-prompts the user if operation is not recognized):**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class RealCalc {

    // Declare the constants
    private static final String YES = "YES";

    private static final String MULTIPLY = "Multiply";
    private static final String DIVIDE = "Divide";
    private static final String SUBTRACT = "Subtract";
    private static final String ADD = "Add";

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // Using one only Scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double fnum, snum;

        System.out.println("Hello, my name is Cortana,"
                + " would you like to perform operations with me?");

        // Use equalsIgnoreCase to make it case-insensitive
        if(sc.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase(YES)) {

            System.out.println("Good choice!\n");

            System.out.print("Enter your first number: ");
            fnum = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter your second number: ");
            snum = sc.nextDouble();

            // This is used to clear the '\n' character following the previous
            // integer input
            sc.nextLine();

            // Call the function to perform arithmetic operations
            performOperation(sc, fnum, snum);
        }

        System.out.println("Thank you!");
    }

    public static void performOperation(Scanner sc, double fnum, double snum) {

        System.out.println("\n" + MULTIPLY + ", " + DIVIDE + ", " + SUBTRACT + ", or " + ADD);
        System.out.println("What do you want me to do with these numbers?");    
        String operation = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println();
        if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase(MULTIPLY)) {
            System.out.printf("%8.3f * %8.3f = %8.3f%n%n", fnum, snum, fnum * snum);
        }
        else if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase(DIVIDE)) {
            System.out.printf("%8.3f / %8.3f = %8.3f%n%n", fnum, snum, fnum / snum);
        }
        else if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase(SUBTRACT)) {
            System.out.printf("%8.3f - %8.3f = %8.3f%n%n", fnum, snum, fnum - snum);
        }
        else if(operation.equalsIgnoreCase(ADD)) {
            System.out.printf("%8.3f + %8.3f = %8.3f%n%n", fnum, snum, fnum + snum);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Sorry, I do not recognize this operation.\n");

            // Call this function again to re-prompt the user for a valid operation
            performOperation(sc, fnum, snum);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output (Division):**

```
Hello, my name is Cortana, would you like to perform operations with me?
yes
Good choice!

Enter your first number: 10
Enter your second number: 20

Multiply, Divide, Subtract, or Add
What do you want me to do with these numbers?
no

Sorry, I do not recognize this operation.


Multiply, Divide, Subtract, or Add
What do you want me to do with these numbers?
haha

Sorry, I do not recognize this operation.


Multiply, Divide, Subtract, or Add
What do you want me to do with these numbers?
divide

  10.000 /   20.000 =    0.500

Thank you!
```

**Note:**

- Declare only one Scanner
- Declare "Yes", "Multiply", etc as constants using the `static final` keywords
- Use `equalsIgnoreCase` to make the comparison case-insensitive
- Use `sc.nextLine();` to clear the `'\n'` character following the previous integer input before asking for the operation to be performed
- Use `if - elseif - else` to go through the different options
- Store the code that prompts the user for an operation inside a function (`performOperation`), call the function again if the 'operation is not recognized'

Comment: I very much appreciate you taking the time to revise my work. Could you briefly clarify What the private static and final keywords mean and do?

Comment: Another comment. Whenever I attempt to use your code, The class `RealCalc{` has an error saying that the RealCalc type is already defined. Am I really dumb, or is this confusing?

Comment: @Peter_Browning Do you realize that you are asking that stuff that can be easily found on the web in Java tutorials should be rewritten especially for you?

Comment: @Peter_Browning I think you already have a class called RealCalc? If that's the case, just replace the code inside with the one shown in my answer. As for those keywords (private, static, final), you should go read some basic Java tutorials for a better understanding. Trying to explain everything in detail would be rather difficult for a Q&A site like this.

Comment: @Peter_Browning I realized you wanted the program to prompt the user again for another input if the operation is not recognized, I have edited my answer to reflect that.